# Box2D tree cost heuristic

Tags: algorithm, box2d, binary-tree

I am using the tree from [Box 2D](https://code.google.com/p/box2d/source/browse/trunk/Box2D/Box2D/Collision/b2DynamicTree.cpp#187) in my project. It is an external (leaf-oriented) binary tree, each node has an axis-aligned bounding box, parent node bounding box is an union of its leaves boxes. When adding a new node, the algorithm goes down the tree and decides where to place it, calculating the costs. The code:

```
//current is the node on the current level, node is the node being added
currentPerimeter=current.box.perimeter;
combinedPerimeter=(current.box ∪ node.box).perimeter;
//the cost of adding the node to the current level
currentCost=2*combinedPerimeter;
//the cost of going down further
inheritanceCost=2*(combinedPerimeter-currentPerimeter);

//calculating the cost of adding the node to the left subtree
lCombinedRect=(node.box ∪ current.leftNode.box);
if(current.leftNode.isLeaf){
   leftCost=inheritanceCost+lCombinedRect.perimeter;
} else {
   leftCost=inheritanceCost+lCombinedRect.perimeter-current.leftNode.box.perimeter;
}
//the same code is for the right subtree
```

If the `currentCost` is the lowest, the node is added to the current level, else the same actions are performed for the right or left child.

The problem is that I don't understand the cost heuristic. In first revisions there was a surface area heuristic, but now it is different. Could you explain what is the aim of the heuristic, what parameters does it minimize? I also want to modify the tree, adding  z-index interval data to the tree nodes. How should I modify the heuristic then?

Comment: This is probably a question for the Box2D forums. But I would guess that it was changed from area to perimeter, because a very long thin bounding box would have a small area, but actually covers a lot of distance so should be considered a higher cost.

Comment: @iforce2d I've already asked there, but still no reply. Surface area heuristic does not use areas, but the product of perimeter and number of children. Probably the perimeter is like a surface area for a 3D bounding box.